# How to fill an area with low leveled floating still water in Minecraft 1.8.9?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

[image: Screenshot of the described water]I once saw this type of water in a parkour server. But when I want to create a map in singleplayer I can't work out how it can be placed. I know `/setblock` to set water level, but it can only place one single water block. If I use `/fill` the water will flow away because it's not water source.

I appreciate everyone who answers the question.

Comment: This is basically a bug. Placing or removing any block around it will make it disappear. Maybe this was done with mods or map editors, I know no way to do it in Vanilla. Even `/setblock` sometimes updates blocks, I think. But maybe in this case just doing a lot of `/setblock` could work? If not rightaway, try it in a different order, because block updates are sometimes different in different directions or locations (which is a huge mess and one of the many reasons why I want [MC-108](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-108) to be fixed).

Comment: @FabianRöling They made the water for the jump, it's part of the jump and the difficulty will dramatically decrease without water. I once tried to spam /setblock but I couldn't find the correct order, and it was not all still water (flowing water surrounding the still). I wonder do you know any mod or something that can do this.

Comment: You can disable block updates from /fill using carpet mod

Comment: @IceFreez3r Is there carpet mod for 1.8.9?

Comment: No, but maybe you can downgrade a region file. Or upgrade, why do you not do that?

Comment: @FabianRöling 1.8.9 is standard version for parkour for some reasons. It can be puzzling but it is.